# How does Java Spring @Autowired work with interface inheriting from several interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a Java Spring Framework project. After a bit of googling I found a way to include custom JPA methods into a JpaRepository. The injection of my repository into my service class using @Autowired works, but I can't understand how Spring handles the injection in this case. Could someone explain how Spring does the injection of CalendarEventRepository into CalendarEventService when the method implementations are in separate classes. It finds the JpaRepository implementation somewhere and my own custom implementation class with my custom method. Howcome their methods are accessible through the same reference variable calendarEventRepository? Bonus question: how does Spring find and instantiate the implementation for JpaRepository?

```
public interface CalendarEventRepository extends JpaRepository<CalendarEvent, Long>, CalendarEventRepositoryCustom { }

public interface CalendarEventRepositoryCustom {
public List<CalendarEvent> findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria(CalendarEventSearchCriteria searchCriteria);
}

public class CalendarEventRepositoryImpl implements
CalendarEventRepositoryCustom {
public List<CalendarEvent> findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria(CalendarEventSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
     }
}

public class CalendarEventService {
@Autowired
CalendarEventRepository calendarEventRepository;
...
calendarEventRepository.delete(calendarEvent);
...
return  calendarEventRepository.findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria(searchCriteria);
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Spring JPA repository interface (`extend JpaRepository` class), the important thing is that the implementation of the interface is generated at runtime. Method names are used by Spring to determine what the method should (since you have written the name `findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria` correctly, it means that you already know that). In your particular case, `CalendarEventRepository` extends `CalendarEventRepositoryCustom` and therefore has a method `findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria(...)`, and also extends `JpaRepository<CalendarEvent, Long>`, which means that it should be treated as JPA repository, and the corresponding implementation should be generated.

To enable the generation of the repository implementation, you need to either include `<jpa:repositories base-package="..." />` to your XML configuration file, or `@Configuration @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackage = "...")` When you have these, that's all the information Spring needs to generate (instantiate) repository and add it to application contexts, and the inject it into other beans. In your case, `@Autowired CalendarEventRepository calendarEventRepository;` specifies where it should be injected. I guess it more answers bonus question than the main one, but seems better to start with it.

I haven't yet touched `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl`. You should use such class if you want to drop the mentioned generation of repository implementation for particular methods. Spring looks for a class which name equals to repository interface's name + "Impl". If such class exists, Spring merges its methods with generated ones. So, see for yourself whether auto-generated `findCalendarEventsBySearchCriteria` method fits your needs or you want to implement it yourself. If the generated one fits, you should consider removing `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` at all.

Comment: Interestingly, `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` should not implement `CalendarEventRepository`. You have done this correctly. So, again, to clarify regarding "Spring does the injection of CalendarEventRepository into CalendarEventService when the method implementations are in separate classes". It is so, because generated methods and manually implemented ones are merged, i.e., if there in no hand-written implementation, the generated one is used; hand-written is used otherwise. That's how the JpaRepository bean (implementation instance) is formed at run-time.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know Spring could do that merging. Is there a way to call a method of the JpaRepository implementation from my custom implmementation? I'd need to do stuff in my custom method and then call the standard JpaRepository methods but I'm getting a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException saying the bean "with name 'calendarEventRepositoryImpl' has been injected into other beans [calendarEventRepository] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped". Autowiring a reference to a repository interface in the implementation class seems to cause this.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, don't have experience :). But consider separating responsibilities between `CalendarEventRepository` and other class that uses this repository, for example, let's call it `CalendarEventRepositoryDecorator`. The decorator could do stuff before and after calling the standard JpaRepository methods. Essentially,  Decorator design pattern would be implemented this way.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll have to have a look at decorator pattern. What I mostly need to do is things like removing references from ORM persisted objects to one I am about to delete from the database. I decided to make my repository interfaces and their implementations and the latter have a reference to JpaRepository implementation so that I have access to their basic CRUD methods. I also considered callbacks (@PreRemove etc.) and entitylisteners but I don't like the idea of having such stuff in entity classes when I have other code in services and repos. This has been a learning experience!

Comment: Actually, what you wanted to do with `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` is a better implementation of Decorator pattern than the one I suggested earlier, because, `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl implements
CalendarEventRepositoryCustom`. If you want to go with this solution, just rename `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` a little bit, not to be exactly "CalendarEventRepositoryImpl", because otherwise Spring uses it in JpaRepository implementation generation, and you get `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`. So you should be able to autowire `CalendarEventRepository` bean into this class.

Comment: Also, you will need to change type of interface of `@Autowired
CalendarEventRepository calendarEventRepository;` in the `CalendarEventService`, because otherwise the generated `JpaRepository` will be injected, and not your custom implementation. Hint: you could annotate your own repository implementation as `@Primary`, and autowire object of `CalendarEventRepositoryCustom` interface into the service class. It should work. If you don't mind, please notify how it went :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Could someone explain how Spring does the injection of
   CalendarEventRepository into CalendarEventService when the method
   implementations are in separate classes.

Answer: First, and most important - all Spring beans are managed - they "live" inside a container, called "application context".

Regardless of which type of configuration you are usin (Java or xml based) you enable "Component Scanning" this helps Spring determine which resource to inject.

How spring determines which bean to inject:

- Matches the names.
- Matches the type.

You even use Qualifiers to narrow down the search for spring.

2. It finds the JpaRepository implementation somewhere and my own
   custom implementation class with my custom method. Howcome their
   methods are accessible through the same reference variable
   calendarEventRepository?

This is more of a java core question of inheritance. Since `JpaRepository`, `CalendarEventRepositoryCustom` and `CalendarEventRepository` are the base classes (implementations) of your `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` so any method/field that is public or protected is available to `CalendarEventRepositoryImpl` class.

Here you are using "Program though interface" your reference variable here is `calendarEventRepository` which is an interface (parent) and that is why you are able to access the fields/methods.

3. Bonus question: how does Spring find and instantiate the
   implementation for JpaRepository?

In spring configuration (java based) you tell spring to search for JPARepositories as below:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages =  {
    "com.package"}
, entityManagerFactoryRef = "EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager"
    )
```

This is how spring gets to know which beans to create.

**I recommend reading out Spring in Action (2nd to 4th Edition) by Craig Walls.**

You can as well go through the https://spring.io/docs

Annotations (Autowired, Inject, your custom) works because of AOP. Read a bit about AOP and you will know how that works.